# Cannot use UITextField in flash project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I have a flash/actionscript3 project that creates an SWF to use in a webpage.

I'm modifying it  to use mx.core.UITextField in place of flash.text.TestField. I'm not able to find the class UITextField in my project libraries and compiler throws errors saying

```
Call to a possibly undefined method UITextField.
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: UITextField.
```

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 with Flash Pro CS6.

Please let me know which library I need to include to work with UITextField class.

Answer (score 1):

[UITextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UITextField.html) is a part of Flex framework. Some official [information](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html) by Adobe. Some official [information](http://flex.apache.org/about-whatis.html) by Apache.